# Check if property is undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript (sandbox [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAZWCgDcSBRKKaOAXjipqjgDI4BvAKDl7iwDOkAHYDgALjgAlYEIijgAbh59BAV1QxJM5NAQAeATCgBLYQHMANHHTDcAPmV84R9DDUCAwhCSThagFsAIxJlAF9lLgAzNWFkGBN5OGQACxQAayZoAAoSKEliMkpqWgAfRhKoAEpOFV4TKLhc6gA6V3cvH2Aa7mdnOrgwriGuIA)):

```
export declare type ServerError = Error & {
    response: Response;
    result: Record<string, any>;
    statusCode: number;
};

function checkError(err: ServerError | Error) {
    if (err.statusCode) {

    }
}
```

Is there a tsconfig option I could enable so that I can check if err.statusCode exists without getting a type error? It makes sense to throw an error if I was trying to store a possibly undefined prop in another variable, or pass it into a function, but shouldn't I be able to at least check if it exists???

Comment: The easy way is `if ('statusCode' in err) ...`

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1260